# why am I getting two legends in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting a graph in seaborn. but I am getting two legends. When I do `legends=False`, I get no legends.

I was trying to move the legend from the center of the graph to center left.

```py
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
#create lineplot of 'day_since_first_confirmed' and 'Confirmed'
sns.relplot(x='day_since_first_confirmed', y='Confirmed', kind='line', 
            data=df_case_a, hue='continent', ci=None)
plt.legend(loc='center left')
plt.title('Corona Virus Confirmed Cases by Continent')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Odd behavior indeed.... Could you extend your example code so it can be tried out directly without any modifications, i.e. add the `import seaborn as sns` and so forth, and maybe fudge some minimal example data with `data=pd.DataFrame({'day_since_first_confirmed':[1,2,3],'Confirmed':[42,13,99],'continent':['Windows', 'MacOS', 'Linux']})` or so? Also, this might be a bug, so if nobody answers in a few days, you might want to try report it to https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `replot()` is a figure-level function that [creates a `FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) under the hood. That means that it is meant to create several subplots, faceted across one or several categorical variables, and that it creates a single legend, which is incompatible with the axes-level legend created by `plt.legend()`

It looks like you are trying to plot only a single plot, and not a `FacetGrid`. In that case, you should use [`sns.lineplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot) instead.

```
sns.lineplot(x='day_since_first_confirmed', y='Confirmed', 
            data=df_case_a, hue='continent', ci=None)
plt.legend(loc='center left')
plt.title('Corona Virus Confirmed Cases by Continent')
```